# Obtain subimages from a binary image with specified neighbourhood

Tags: image-processing, list-manipulation

Lets say I have this binary picture (an array with 1's and 0's):

```
start = {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}};
i = ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[<|"OuterTotalisticCode"->224,"Dimension"->2,"Neighborhood"->9|>,{start,0},{{{200}}}],Frame->False,ColorRules->{1->White,0->Black}]
```

[image]

Then I can extract the subimages e.g. by using:

```
subimages =  ComponentMeasurements[i, "Image", All, "PropertyAssociation"]["Image"]
```

[image]

This gives me 13 subimages which have one black pixel in between. (Note, that the blank entries above are white pixels and thus the result is correct.)

But now I would like to count subimages **with two black pixels in between** as one subimage. More precisely I would like to obtain only a result with 9 subimages as grouped as this:

[image]

Is there any obvious way to do it in Mathematica?

## Edit:

The answers by @MarcoB and @kglr work for the specified example. Especially if one uses additionally an `Erosion` on the mask to trim down the boundaries.
But the solution is not generally applicable, another example:

```
start = {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
i = ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[<|"OuterTotalisticCode" -> 224, "Dimension" -> 2,"Neighborhood" -> 9|>, {start, 0}, {{{400}}}], Frame -> False,ColorRules -> {1 -> White, 0 -> Black}];
```

The resulting image should be, as before, divided into subimages with 2 black cells in between, as this (the critical location where the suggested solutions fail is indicated with the arrow):

[image]

This was the proposed solution (with an added `Erosion`):

```
dilated = Dilation[i, DiskMatrix[1]];
mask = Erosion[MorphologicalComponents@dilated, 1];
subimages = ComponentMeasurements[{i, mask}, "Image"]
```

[image]

Image 4 was captured incorrectly. To me it seems that `ComponentMeasurements` applies a bounding box which is not desired. Any modification of the proposed solution that fixes this issue is appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `start` in your code?

Comment: sorry, thanks for asking, I edited.

Comment: Your edit changes the question substantially, to the point of invalidating all answers provided so far. Moving the goalposts like you just did is frowned upon because it wastes the effort put in by answer writers, and discourages further answers because people will be worried that you will substantially change the question yet again. Consider removing your edit, accepting an answer to your original question, and perhaps posting your new problem as a new question.

Comment: @MarcoB I disagree with your statement. The first picture just served as an (arbitrary) example and the question was framed generally. While the provided solutions gave correct answers to the example they didn't give the correct answer to the (general) question. But if there won't be further answers I will accept one answer given and ask another question, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

```
start1 = {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}};
ca1 = CellularAutomaton[<|"OuterTotalisticCode" -> 224, "Dimension" -> 2, 
"Neighborhood"->9|>, {start,0}, {{{200}}}];
i1 = ArrayPlot[ca1, Frame-> False, ColorRules -> {1 -> White, 0 -> Black}];
```

Using a combination of `ArrayMesh` and `FindClusters` with `ChessboardDistance` we get a list of clusters of polygon objects:

```
clusters1 = FindClusters[MeshPrimitives[ArrayMesh[ca1], 2],
  DistanceFunction -> (ChessboardDistance[RegionCentroid @ #, RegionCentroid @ #2]&)];

Show[i1, Graphics @ MapIndexed[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{ Dotted, Cyan}], 
     Scale[BoundingRegion[Join @@ (PolygonCoordinates /@ #), 
       "FastEllipse"], {1, 1} 1.1], EdgeForm[], Opacity[1], 
     FaceForm[ColorData[97]@#2[[1]]], #} &, clusters1]]
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[Graphics[{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[White], #}, 
   Background -> Black, ImageSize -> Tiny, PlotRangePadding -> 1]& /@ 
 clusters1, 5]
```

[image]

```
start2 = {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
ca2 = CellularAutomaton[<|"OuterTotalisticCode" -> 224, "Dimension" -> 2, 
 "Neighborhood" -> 9|>, {start2, 0}, {{{400}}}];

i2 = ArrayPlot[ca2, Frame -> False, ColorRules -> {1 -> White, 0 -> Black}];


clusters2 = FindClusters[MeshPrimitives[ArrayMesh[ca2], 2],
 DistanceFunction -> (ChessboardDistance[RegionCentroid @ #,RegionCentroid @ #2]&)];

Show[i2, Graphics @ MapIndexed[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{ Dotted, Cyan}], 
   Scale[BoundingRegion[Join @@ (PolygonCoordinates /@ #), "FastEllipse"], 
     {1, 1} 1.1], 
   EdgeForm[], Opacity[1],  FaceForm[ColorData[97]@#2[[1]]], #} &, clusters2]]
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[Graphics[{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[White], #}, 
   Background -> Black, ImageSize -> Tiny, PlotRangePadding -> 1]& /@ 
 clusters2, 5]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
trim = Values @ ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalTransform[Binarize @ i, "Max"], 
   "BoundingBox"];

ImageTrim[i, trim]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however your solution is not quite correct for a different example. Please have a look at the edit I made. Do you have any idea how to adjust it appropriately?

Comment: @MrPuh, I missed the _two black cells in between_ bit (although it is boldfaced in your post:).

Comment: Your answer was correct for the first example I provided! It just doesn't give the right result for a different example. Any thoughts on how to fix it is appreciated :)

Answer (score 8):

One simple approach is to expand the small blocks using Dilation, then count the number of blocks that remain. Starting with your image i:

```
idil = Dilation[i, 2];
subidil = ComponentMeasurements[idil, "Image", All, "PropertyAssociation"]["Image"]
```

and you can see that subidil has the desired Length[subidil]=9 components.

This is an answer to the original question, which was: "to count subimages with two black pixels in between as one subimage". It is not an answer to the extended and revised (twice) question.

Comment: This wouldn't give me the actual subimages though, but a "thicker" version. I tried `Erosion` afterwards but this doesn't really work.

Comment: You could use the output of subidil as masks on the original set if you want finer control.

Comment: Not sure if I get what you mean. How would I do this?

Comment: Overlay each of the smaller older ones (in subimg) to its appropriate new larger one (in subidil). ComponentMeasurements will tell you where they are.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to what @bill proposed, but generating the separated images.

First, use dilation to "fuse together" the small features that are close by. Then use MorphologicalComponents to generate a mask identifying each of the dilated components. Finally, use that mask to extract the subimages *of the original image* that correspond to where the fused blobs are in the dilated image.

```
dilated = Dilation[i, DiskMatrix[1]];
mask = MorphologicalComponents@dilated;
ComponentMeasurements[{i, mask}, "Image"]
```

[image: separated components]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however your solution is not quite correct for a different example. Please have a look at the edit I made. Do you have any idea how to adjust it appropriately?

Comment: @MrPuh Moving the goalposts like you just did is VERY unfriendly to those that put in the effort of writing an answer to your original question, only to see it invalidated because you had not thought the question through properly. Consider removing your edit, accepting an answer to the original question, and perhaps posting your new problem as a new question.

Comment: Sorry if you feel I have moved the goalpost, I thought I just explained the question better with another example (it is still the same question: extracting subimages with 2 black cells in between). Your answer helped me in any way so your appreciated effort was by no means ineffectual. Thank you for that.
I am not trying to downplay your answer, I am just trying to find a general answer to the (general) problem.